# Как получить hwid в Python?

Tags: python

Попробовал получить [этим способом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38328176/getting-a-unique-hardware-id-with-python), но в переменную hwid не записывается, а просто выводится в консоль при исполнении функции, к тому же нужно таскать exe приложение. Есть ещё какой-нибудь способ получения hwid в питоне?

Comment: Используйте `subprocess.check_output()`, чтобы получить вывод в переменную.

Comment: А что-то другое всё-таки есть?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2461141

Comment: А зачем мне mac адрес?

Comment: Почитайте ответы к вопросу - там есть разные решения.

Comment: Там ответы все про mac адрес

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я немного идиот и неправильно задал вопрос, оказывается хотел я не номер жёсткого диска, но в итоге нашёл, что нужно.

```
from wmi import WMI  
a = WMI().Win32_ComputerSystemProduct()[0].UUID
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Ответ взят отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/a/4194146/3848611

Для Linux:

```
import sys, os, fcntl, struct

if os.geteuid() >  0:
    print("ERROR: Must be root to use")
    sys.exit(1)

with open(sys.argv[1], "rb") as fd:
    # tediously derived from the monster struct defined in <hdreg.h>
    # see comment at end of file to verify
    hd_driveid_format_str = "@ 10H 20s 3H 8s 40s 2B H 2B H 4B 6H 2B I 36H I Q 152H"
    # Also from <hdreg.h>
    HDIO_GET_IDENTITY = 0x030d
    # How big a buffer do we need?
    sizeof_hd_driveid = struct.calcsize(hd_driveid_format_str)

    # ensure our format string is the correct size
    # 512 is extracted using sizeof(struct hd_id) in the c code
    assert sizeof_hd_driveid == 512 

    # Call native function
    buf = fcntl.ioctl(fd, HDIO_GET_IDENTITY, " " * sizeof_hd_driveid)
    fields = struct.unpack(hd_driveid_format_str, buf)
    serial_no = fields[10].strip()
    model = fields[15].strip()
    print("Hard Disk Model: %s" % model)
    print("  Serial Number: %s" % serial_no)
```

для Windows:

```
import wmi
c = wmi.WMI()
for item in c.Win32_PhysicalMedia():
    print item
```

https://pypi.org/project/WMI/

Либо:

```
import win32api
print win32api.GetVolumeInformation("C:\\")
```

http://python.net/crew/mhammond/

Если Вам будет нужна еще какая-либо информация - https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/get-hardware-system-information-python

Comment: Мне нужен hwid, ваша программа даёт случайное число (uuid.uuid1()  # make a UUID based on the host ID and current time).

Comment: hwid - Hardware ID. То есть id жёсткого диска

Comment: HWID - может быть разным, если вам нужен ID - жесткого диска, это совсем другой вопрос

Comment: Думал, что все только одно подразумевают

Comment: для какой вам операционной системы - только linux?

Comment: Windows только нужно

Comment: Получать из ioctl интересная идея, хотя просмотр каталога /dev/disks/by-id проще

Comment: А есть что-то про получение айди процессора? Сетевушки и харды иногда расходный материал..

Comment: @eri вы наверное про такое? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46130851/how-to-get-cpu-serial-number-on-windows-using-python